# Find IDs that match both values

Tags: google-sheets, filter, lambda, concatenation, textjoin

I'm trying to fetch from a table on another sheet, the IDs that have 2 values in common.

At tab `Base`" I have `Name` and `Date`, and would like to have on `Lookup` the `ID`'s from tab `To be fetched` that match both `Name` and `Date`. Marked in green are the matching values I'm talking about.

[image: Tab Base]

This is in tab `To be fetched`
[image: Tab To be fetched]

I was trying with this formula but it's not working. Even if it would, I think it would probably retrieve the 1st match, not all matches but it was a start, I guess.

```
=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP($A$2:$A" "&$B$2:$B,{'To be fetched'!$A$2:$A&" "&'To be fetched'!$C$2:$C,'To be fetched'!$D$2:$D},3,false))
```

But I don't know nor why doesn't it work at all nor how to fully achieve the intended result.

[This](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y9iciU_aoM7KW5ywqZ_oQQ0XfdHB1nmmKewzxUIEfVM/edit#gid=0) is the example google sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use in C2:

```
=IFERROR(BYROW(A2:INDEX(A2:A, COUNTA(A2:A)), 
 LAMBDA(x, TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, FILTER('To be fetched'!D:D, 
 'To be fetched'!C:C=OFFSET(x,,1), 'To be fetched'!A:A=x)))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter()`, like this:

`=iferror( join( ", ", filter('To be fetched'!D$2:D, 'To be fetched'!A$2:A = A2, 'To be fetched'!C$2:C = B2) ) )`

To evaluate that over a number of rows, use a lambda, like this:

```
=lambda( 
  ids, names, dates, 
  map( 
    A2:A, B2:B, 
    lambda( 
      name, date, 
      if( 
        len(name) * len(date), 
        iferror( join( ", ", filter(ids, names = name, dates = date) ) ), 
        iferror(1/0) 
      ) 
    ) 
  )
)('To be fetched'!D2:D, 'To be fetched'!A2:A, 'To be fetched'!C2:C)
```

Comment: Thank you. It works but if I add it as Arrayformula, it doesn't propagate. Nevertheless, it's very clean

Comment: `join()` is an aggregating function and will not give row-by-row results in a normal array formula. Edited the answer to add a lambda. See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y9iciU_aoM7KW5ywqZ_oQQ0XfdHB1nmmKewzxUIEfVM/edit#gid=0).